# Is there a practical way to convert a log potentiometer to an inverse log one?

Tags: potentiometer

I want to convert a log poti to an inverse log poti. The difference is shown below:

[image]

Let's say we have a 10k log poti, is there a practical way to inverse the output so that we can obtain something similar to the green plot above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by swapping the two outer pins of a potentio meter.

For example, pin 1 is connected to 5V, pin 2 is connected to a transistor and pin 3 is connected to ground. Just swap the pins so that: pin 3 is connected to 5V, pin 2 is connected to a transistor and pin 1 is connected to ground.

Edit: as @transistor said: the control direction will be reversed.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the control direction will be reversed. Presumably the OP wants to keep the "clockwise is more" operation of the pot. (And what is a "pot meter"? Potentiometer?)